# assign time to variable

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

this question maybe foolish by me. but i want to understand the standards.

I am creating the online exam application. i want to assign the time for each question while its insertion through UI. what field i have to keep there (on UI? and in code behind? and in database?) ? Timespan ? or date time ? . if i keep time span then how do i can convert timespan to datetime while loading the set of questions?I am using asp.net mvc and c#

Comment: Why you want convert it to datetime?

Comment: in fact i don't want to do that.please review following discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeSpan` is the time elapsed between two `DateTime`s.

A `DateTime` is a specific time and date, but has no understanding of time usage.

Therefore `DateTime` is the correct to use for you.

**EDIT**

According to your response on another answer, it's the *duration* you are after, and that is contained inside a TimeSpan. If it's minutes, the easiest approach is to use:

```
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( myUserInput );
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to calculate the time usage, then when opening up the question page store the time somewhere:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then when the question is answered, do the following:

```
TimeSpan questionDuration = DateTime.Now - startTime;
```

`questionDuration` will now contain the time used from opening up the question to answering it.

Comment: But it carries Date also , i want to set question time as let say 2 min. it varies for each question. what should i have to take from UI as input then ? integer?

Answer (score 2):

A `TimeSpan` holds a duration, like 60 seconds. A `DateTime` holds a fixed date and time. That's what you should use.

---

When you say "the time" for the question, do you mean how long it should take to answer the question? If so, then you're looking for a duration, so you should use TimeSpan. If you are able to limit this to some number of minutes (with no fractions), then simply use an integer.

Comment: Yes John, but i have UI ,where as, what should i have to take as input from user , date time or timespan?

Comment: @Lalit - What is the user supposed to input? A date? a point in time? Both? Or is he supposed to enter a duration like 10 minutes?

Comment: yes , only minutes. so what i have to take there integer? and i think if i take integer as an input, then i have to convert it is minutes by using datetime ? please correct me. i have no knowledge about datetime at all.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by the "time" for each question. You mean the duration.

Comment: its ok,i want duration for that particular question

Comment: ok , your answers clearing me a lot John. in fact i want to implement both that you saying. means I want to calculate duration for each question itself, as well as want to keep limit for that question. means based on this I want to calculate the student confidence level over that question. as if Limit > 25% of Limit = "have best confidence" , if Limit > 50% of Limit="have good confidence", else if  Limit > 75% of Limit ="have lack of confidence" else if duration = limit then" have poor confidence" like that only.